# weird array behaviour in php

Tags: php, kohana

i'm scratching my head to understand kohana.so its request to treat my question in context of kohana,if suitable.
in routes file i'm watching a weird thing like that

```
'route' => '(<controller>(/<action>(/<keyword>(/<start>(/<limit>)))))
//if i output this line i got noting but  ((/(/(/(/)))))
//it means angle brackets and words between them are not shown.
```

Now my question is that in which cases do we need to code in such a way.Why we are working in such a way if we don't need angle brackets and words between them.

Comment: Use "view source". Have you ever heard of "HTML tag" term?

Answer (score 2):

That's not weird behaviour.

Because a document's default content-type is HTML, it will parse your text as tags. In order to avoid you have to echo using the function [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), or change the content-type.

```
echo htmlspecialchars($array['route']);

// or

header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $array['route'];
```